# Pandas.to_datetime giving an error when given 15-Jan-0001 is there a way around this?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I've got a dataset which goes back to 15-Jan-0001 (yes that is 1 CE!), it was originally 0 CE but since that year doesn't exist I cut those 12 months out of the data.

I am trying to get pandas to convert to date-time string in my datasdf.datetime=pd.to_datetime(df.datetime) to an internal datetime object.

I tried:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.load_csv(file)
df.datetime = pd.to_dtaetime(df.datetime)
```

and got:

```
OutOfBoundsDatetime: Out of bounds nanosecond timestamp: 1-01-15 00:00:00
```

the first two lines of the csv file are:

```
datenum,year,month,day,datetime,data_mean_global,data_mean_nh,data_mean_sh
381,1,1,15,15-Jan-0001 00:00:00,277.876675965034,278.555895908363,277.197456021705
```

Comment: I found the answer to this apparently it is a feature! The way 'round it is to use, in my case, pd.PeriodIndex(start=date_start,end=date_end,freq="M")

Answer (score 0):

One way is convert this problematic values to `NaT`s:

```
df.datetime = pd.to_dtaetime(df.datetime, errors='coerce')
```

Comment: That didn't really help as it puts NaT (presumably Not a Time) into the field. Interestingly the plot now starts in 1689 with all previous data ignored.

Comment: hmmm, then it is problem, because [limits](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#timestamp-limitations). One possible solution should be convert to `PeriodIndex`

Comment: Thankyou again! periodindex will form but won't plot!! Python's datetime module does accept year 1 so next step is to try and apply that. Wish me luck! (Or I might do this in R).

Comment: So how was final solution?

Comment: Still working on one: Pandas is being a bit of a pain here. I may try putting the dataset into a numpy array and plot  from there. Or maybe try using R for this plot (possibly via rpy2 or whatever it is called.

Comment: @so r support this? I never working in r, so no idea.

Comment: Don't know yet for certain, but I suspect it will as R is used in palaeoclimatology.

Comment: I found the answer to this apparently it is a feature! The way 'round it is to use, in my case, pd.PeriodIndex(start=date_start,end=date_end,freq="M")